# Group every n:n+k rows in pandas, where last row plus remainder

Tags: python, pandas

I need to slice my rows into sections of fours. Here you see group 3 is one group, there's 4 group 3. There's two group 4s, where the number of rows in the first dataframe is 4 and the number of the second group 4 is 2.

```
 Go        Per  Votes      group
NaN  40.726126    NaN          3   
NaN  40.727271   36.0          3   
NaN  40.719560    NaN          3   
NaN  40.729198   19.0          3  
NaN  40.726126    NaN          4   
NaN  40.727271   36.0          4   
NaN  40.719560    NaN          4   
NaN  40.729198   19.0          4 
NaN  40.726126    NaN          4   
NaN  40.727271   36.0          4   
NaN  40.719560    NaN          5   
NaN  40.729198   19.0          5
```

Here's what I have

```
for i in unique_group:
    this_group = df_group[df_group['group'] == i]
    count_items = this_group.shape[0]
    if count_items > 4:
            remainder = count_items % 4
            divide = int(count_items / 4)
            repeat_group = divide
        else:
            repeat_group = 1
    for repeat in range(1, repeat_group+1):
        if count_items > 4:
            if repeat==repeat_group:
                this_group = this_group.iloc[:repeat*4+remainder,:]
                print "last group"
            elif repeat == 1:
                this_group = this_group.iloc[:repeat*4,:]
                print "first group"
            else:
                this_group = this_group.iloc[(repeat-1)*4+1:repeat*4,:]        
                print "between group"
        print this_group
```

My output is when I get to group 4, it only prints the first group even though it says last group/or between groups (depends how long my list is).

Comment: I saw 6 row for group 4 not 2

Comment: yea cuz the second group is remainder of 2, so two groups of group 4. Group 1 is 4, group 2 is 2. I shouldve placed a better nomenclature. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your dataframe is called `df`.

```
def chunker(seq, size):
    return (seq[pos:pos + size] for pos in range(0, len(seq), size))

grouped = df.groupby('group')
groups = []
for _, gr in grouped:
    for chunk in chunker(gr, 4):
        groups.append(chunk)

for gr in groups:
    print(len(gr))
```

This will create a list containing all chunked groups.